# i have the error : no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, iframe, nosuchelementexception

Sorry for my english.

I try to click on an element without success.

the link for the web site : https://devis.aesio.fr/adhesion/indiv/devis/aesio-sante-particuliers/39209/identite

You sould then click on the logo Aesio Mutuelle  on top left of the screen and After click on 'en savoir plus' of the frame
Particulier

You could also exécute the two first paragraph of my code
Following

This is my code on python :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'....\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.aesio.fr/")


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='didomi-popup']/div/div/div/span").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='block-contenudelapageprincipale']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='block-contenudelapageprincipale']/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/p/a").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("//*[@id='identite_particulier_civilite']/div[1]/label/span")
```

I have the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-e7b7e4d1cd78>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='identite_particulier_civilite']/div[1]/label/span").click()

  File "D:\logiciels\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

  File "D:\logiciels\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {

  File "D:\logiciels\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

  File "D:\logiciels\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='identite_particulier_civilite']/div[1]/label/span"}
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)
```

I also tried to add to my code without success :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "__tcfapiLocator")))
```

I also tried to add to my code without success too :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("__tcfapiLocator")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", element)
```

If anyone could help that will be very nice

Tranks

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I opened `www.aesio.fr` in browser and I can't find `identite_particulier_civilite` on this page. I can't find even `didomi-popup` on this page. It seems this element doesn't exist - or maybe it need some other code to see it - ie. maybe it needs to login on page. We can't see it in browser so we can't help you

Comment: read again my first comment: put ... **in question** (not comment)

Comment: and put link also in question. More people will see url - so more people may help you.

Comment: your new URL redirect me to login form https://devis.aesio.fr/login - and this page also doesn't have `identite_particulier_civilite`, and it doesn't have even `block-contenudelapageprincipale`. Maybe you have to write code which put login/password in form and click button.

Comment: I don't understand when i put the url  https://devis.aesio.fr/adhesion/indiv/devis/aesio-sante-particuliers/39209/identite, chrome dont send me to https://devis.aesio.fr/login

Comment: by the way, thanks for your advices

Comment: your browser may remeber that you already logged in. Try to `logout` and then check this URL. OR run browser in `private mode` and check URL.

Comment: now I see that when you click `'en savoir plus'` of the frame `Particulier` on main page then it go to `https://devis.aesio.fr/indiv/init` which automatically redirects to url with new unique number - but this shows me form `Vos informations personnelles` with fields `Civilité (Madam/Monsiur)`, `Prénom`, `Nom`, etc. but HTML doesn't have `id='block-contenudelapageprincipale'` nor `@id='identite_particulier_civilite'`. Maybe if you already filled this form you may get different page. But in Selenium it would need to login or maybe get cookies from original browser to have access without login

Comment: Thanks i will follow you advices